# Webform: send uploaded files as attachments

Tags: webforms, emails

> Hi i'm using SMTP module to send uploaded inforamation into mail using webforms.so i'm getting below information to my mail fine but in place of upload Your Cv link i need attachment .

### The following application was received from the website.

==Contact details==
     Title: demo1
     First name: demo
     Surname / Family Name: demo
     Tel (Daytime): xxxxxxxxxx
     Email address: demo@gmail.com
     Currently living in: london
     Prepared to relocate: Yes

==Career choices==
     Job type: Permanent
     Current salary: 200
     Min. salary required: 200
     Were you referred by a friend?
     Upload your CV:http://xxxxx/system/files/webform/uploaded_cvs/demoresume_4.doc

This requirement cab be done using MIME module and Mail System but it's take more time to submit form.

Please help me i'm new to drupal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- All sorted in the end with host entries on the server,I have updated
  host entries for sending email and added domain name as host entry
  then webform very fast to submited .it's works for me